# In Field Service Lightning, what can a normal Service Cloud user do?

Tags: field-service-lightning

We're considering using Field Service Lightning for a customer who needs to perform jobs like tracking the maintenance of their assets.

In our scenario, the customer has lots of assets, but a relatively small team, and only two locations. In a way, you could call their requirements Service Lightning, rather than Field Service Lightning.

So, they don't really need a complicated way of dispatching mobile technicians.

I've follow the documentation and Trailheads to get a general feel for FSL, and it seems like a good fit. But, the part I'm struggling with is licencing. I've asked Salesforce, but despite a fairly long email thread and a phone call, I'm not convinced that they understand what I'm asking. So, I thought I'd try on here before I go back and ask them again.

It boils down to these questions:

- If we buy FSL (e.g. one dispatcher licence), is that enough to get the Maintenance Plans, Work Types, etc. enabled in the org?
- Will normal Service Cloud users be able to access (ideally edit/create) those types through the standard interface?

To be clear, we don't have much of a need for the advanced UI stuff in the FSL managed package (the Gantt chart and so on). We just want the object structure and the automated way to create Work Orders from Maintenance Plans.